# Debian etch apt-get issues

Tags: debian, svn, apt, aptitude, debian-etch

I'm new to this area of Linux.  I have a linux box which says kernel version is 2.6.18-4-amd64.  It's been working as it for a long time.
I needed to install subversion on the box, hence I tried apt-get.  But received following:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libneon26 libsvn1
Suggested packages:
  subversion-tools db4.4-util
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libneon26 libsvn1 subversion
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
Need to get 1802kB of archives.
After unpacking 5263kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Fetched 1802kB in 1s (1001kB/s)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_main_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/contrib Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/non-free Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
Selecting previously deselected package libneon26.
(Reading database ... 42258 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libneon26 (from .../libneon26_0.26.2-4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libsvn1.
Unpacking libsvn1 (from .../libsvn1_1.4.2dfsg1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package subversion.
Unpacking subversion (from .../subversion_1.4.2dfsg1-3_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libneon26 (0.26.2-4) ...
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 is not a symbolic link

Setting up libsvn1 (1.4.2dfsg1-3) ...
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 is not a symbolic link

Setting up subversion (1.4.2dfsg1-3) ...
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_main_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/contrib Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/non-free Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Upon running apt-get update I get following:

```
.....
 Fetched 4332kB in 5s (786kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/etch/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 193.62.202.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/etch/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 193.62.202.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/etch/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 193.62.202.28 80]

Reading package lists... Done

W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_main_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/contrib Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/non-free Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_main_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/contrib Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/non-free Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian-security_dists_etch_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages) - stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ etch main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, Subversion should be installed correctly.  As the others mentioned etch is dead.

Answer (score 5):

All final security updates for Etch were rolled into a [final minor release](http://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100522) at EOL.  Thus all security updates are in the main debian repo for etch, all you need in your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
```

Comment: As @Zoredache said, it did install subversion correctly.  Thanks Chad - I was missing deb-src in my source.list- I wasn't aware about security update being rolled into main repo.  Now my apt-get update runs clean.<br/>  I'll update to lenny to squeeze soon.

Answer (score 3):

Etch support has been discontinued for debian. Upgrade your distribution to a later one. Like [squeeze](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/)